# how to access subframe by frame's src in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

```
import mechanize,urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = mechanize.Browser()
cj = mechanize.CookieJar()
browser.set_cookiejar(cj)
browser.open("http://cyber.yu.ac.kr/lecture/index.php")
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser.form['txtUser'] = "stack"
browser.form['txtPwd'] = "overflow"
browser.submit()
a=browser.open("http://cyber.yu.ac.kr/lecture/mypage.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(a,'lxml')
lframe = soup.find(id='leftFrame')
print lframe['src']
print('http://cyber.yu.ac.kr/lecture/'+lframe['src'][2:])
b= browser.open('http://cyber.yu.ac.kr/lecture/'+lframe['src'][2:])
```

In blow ficture, I want to access left frame by frame's src,
i can access by click the frame, but code isn't working

```
Error is : mechanize_response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What if you find the URL of the left frame manually (from clicking) and then just go there directly in your script?